# How to configure Neo4j to run in a minimal memory environment?

Tags: memory, neo4j, cypher

For demo purposes, I am running Neo4j in a low memory environment -- A laptop with 4GB of RAM, 1644MB is use for video memory, leaving only 2452 MB available for use..   It's also running SQL Server, our WCF services, and our clients..   So there's little memory for Neo4j.

I'm running LOAD CSV cypher scripts via REST from a C# service.  There are more than 20 scripts, and theyt work well in a server environment.   I've written code to paginate, so that they run in smaller batches.  I've reduced the batch size very low ( 25 csv rows ) and a given script may do 300 batches, but I continue to get "Java heap space" errors at some point.

I've tried configuring Neo4j with a relatively large heap space ( 640MB ) which is all the available RAM size plus setting the cache_type to none,  and it gets much further before I get the java heap space error.   What I don't understand is in that case, why does it grow that much?   Also until I restart the neo4j service, I get these java heap space errors quickly.   The batch size doesn't seem to impact how much memory is used appreciably.

However, after doing that, and I run the application with these settings, the query performance becomes very slow due to the cache settings.

I am running this on a Windows 7 laptop with 4G RAM -- using Neo4j 2.2.1 Community Edition.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can share your LOAD CSV statement and the other queries you run.

I think you just run into this:

http://markhneedham.com/blog/2014/10/23/neo4j-cypher-avoiding-the-eager/

So `PROFILE` or `EXPLAIN` your queries and make it not to use that much intermediate state. We can help if you share your statements.

And you should use `PERIODIC COMMIT 100`.

Something like:

```
heap=512M
dbms.pagecache.memory=200M
keep_logical_logs=false
cache_type=none
```

http://console.neo4j.org runs neo4j in memory putting up to 50 instances in a single gigabyte of memory. So it should be doable.

Comment: This solved my immediate problem...   However. looking at the generated plan for a relatively simple case, I am definitely getting some of the "eager" stuff happening, and pulling in way more records than I should be.   Need to understand why that is happening.  But that's a separate question and answer.   Thanks much!